# Find number of pairs (A[i], A[j]) such that A[i] <= A[j] + c, i < j (c is given constant). [O(N^2) solution not accepted]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

O(N^2) solution is not accepted so brute force cannot be applied.

I am stuck and can't think of any other algorithm.

I thought of applying binary search but the array is not sorted and we need the original indices for the condition i < j.

Can we use inversion count concept here? (I have seen it used for A[i]>2*A[j] but will it work for this question?)

Please help.

Comment: Yes, you need to use the concept of [inversion counts](https://www.techiedelight.com/inversion-count-array/) which is a similar to traditional merge sort (divide-and-conquer).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a variant of merge sort here.
Given an array A[0...n/2...n-1], let us divide it into two parts left and right.
Left is A[0...n/2-1] 
Right is A[n/2...n]

Now calculate the no. of such pairs in left & right arrays using function f(array) which also sorts the array 
Now we called f on "Left" and we got no. of such pairs in left with left array sorted. Similarly for the right one.
Now given these two parts, how will you find no of such required pairs in A?
We have count for "Left" & "Right", and now just need to find pairs (x, y) such that x is in Left; y is in Right; x <= y + c. 
Remember that we already called this function on left & right so elements are sorted. Now just write modified merge of those two arrays which in-addition to sorting also counts no. of such pairs by maintaining index in left array which has not seen any left[index] <= y + c for elements y in right.

Implementation

```
public (int, int[]) merge(int[] arr, int c){
        lanswer, left = merge(left);
        ranswer, right = merge(right);
        
        int lsize = left.length;
        int rsize = right.length;

        int p = 0; // left index
        int q = 0; // right index
        int r = 0; // combined index
        int lIndex = 0; // least index in left array for which left[lIndex] > right[q] + c

        int answer = lanswer + ranswer;

        while(p < lsize && q < rsize){

            if(left[p] >= right[q]){
                arr[r] = left[p];
                r += 1;
                p += 1;
            }
            else{
                while(right[q] >= left[lIndex] - c){
                    answer += (rsize - q);
                    lIndex += 1;
                }
                arr[r] = right[q];
                q += 1;
                r += 1;
            }
        }

        while(p < lsize){
            arr[r] = left[p];
            r += 1;
            p += 1;
        }

        while(q < rsize){
            while(right[q] >= left[lIndex] - c){
                answer += (rsize - q);
                lIndex += 1;
            }
            arr[r] = right[q];
            q += 1;
            r += 1;
        }
        
        return (answer, arr);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Doubt: Why did you take `if (left[p] >= right[p])` It will sort array in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

Use a balanced tree, e.g. AVL tree. Additionally you store the number of nodes in the sub tree for each node or edge. Now you can just go backwards through the array and find the number of nodes >= A[i] - c in O(logn). This is the count for A[i]. Then add A[i] to the tree and proceed.

With the AVL tree with height of subtree from geeksforce (see below), runs in O(nlogn):

```java
public static int solve(int[] a, int c) {
    if (a == null || a.length == 0)
        return 0;
    Node root = insert(null, a[a.length - 1]);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = a.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        count += countNodesGreaterEqual(root, a[i] - c);
        root = insert(root, a[i]);
    }
    return count;
}

public static int countNodesGreaterEqual(Node node, int k) {
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    if (node.key == k)
        return 1 + (node.right != null ? node.right.size : 0);
    if (node.key < k)
        return countNodesGreaterEqual(node.right, k);
    // node.key > k
    return 1 + (node.right != null ? node.right.size : 0) +
            countNodesGreaterEqual(node.left, k);
}
```

AVL tree with height implementation from geeksforce [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-inversions-in-an-array-set-2-using-self-balancing-bst/)

```java
// An AVL tree node
static class Node
{
    int key, height;
    Node left, right;
 
    // Size of the tree rooted
    // with this Node
    int size;
}
 
// A utility function to get the height of
// the tree rooted with N
static int height(Node N)
{
    if (N == null)
        return 0;
         
    return N.height;
}
 
// A utility function to size of the
// tree of rooted with N
static int size(Node N)
{
    if (N == null)
        return 0;
         
    return N.size;
}
 
// A utility function to create a new node
static Node newNode(int ele)
{
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.key = ele;
    temp.left = null;
    temp.right = null;
    temp.height = 1;
    temp.size = 1;
    return temp;
}
 
// A utility function to right rotate
// subtree rooted with y
static Node rightRotate(Node y)
{
    Node x = y.left;
    Node T2 = x.right;
 
    // Perform rotation
    x.right = y;
    y.left = T2;
 
    // Update heights
    y.height = Math.max(height(y.left),
                        height(y.right)) + 1;
    x.height = Math.max(height(x.left),
                        height(x.right)) + 1;
 
    // Update sizes
    y.size = size(y.left) + size(y.right) + 1;
    x.size = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
 
    // Return new root
    return x;
}
 
// A utility function to left rotate
// subtree rooted with x
static Node leftRotate(Node x)
{
    Node y = x.right;
    Node T2 = y.left;
 
    // Perform rotation
    y.left = x;
    x.right = T2;
 
    // Update heights
    x.height = Math.max(height(x.left),
                        height(x.right)) + 1;
    y.height = Math.max(height(y.left),
                        height(y.right)) + 1;
 
    // Update sizes
    x.size = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
    y.size = size(y.left) + size(y.right) + 1;
 
    // Return new root
    return y;
}
 
// Get Balance factor of Node N
static int getBalance(Node N)
{
    if (N == null)
        return 0;
         
    return height(N.left) - height(N.right);
}
 
// Inserts a new key to the tree rooted with Node.
static Node insert(Node node, int key)
{
     
    // 1. Perform the normal BST rotation
    if (node == null)
        return (newNode(key));
 
    if (key < node.key)
        node.left = insert(node.left, key);
    else
        node.right = insert(node.right, key);
 
    // 2. Update height and size of
    // this ancestor node
    node.height = Math.max(height(node.left),
                           height(node.right)) + 1;
    node.size = size(node.left) +
                size(node.right) + 1;
 
    // 3. Get the balance factor of this
    // ancestor node to check whether this
    // node became unbalanced
    int balance = getBalance(node);
 
    // If this node becomes unbalanced,
    // then there are 4 cases
 
    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && key < node.left.key)
        return rightRotate(node);
 
    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && key > node.right.key)
        return leftRotate(node);
 
    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && key > node.left.key)
    {
        node.left = leftRotate(node.left);
        return rightRotate(node);
    }
 
    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && key < node.right.key)
    {
        node.right = rightRotate(node.right);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }
 
    // Return the (unchanged) node pointer
    return node;
}
```

Comment: I read about AVL Tree( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-inversions-in-an-array-set-2-using-self-balancing-bst/ ).  I am not understanding how to modify insert function to get the result.

Comment: @Rakesh nice find. In this case I can post the code, I was just too lazy to implement the AVL tree.

Comment: I wish I could collapse that lower code part, but it doesn't work. Changed smaller equal to greater equal, that was a mistake in the answer.